# how not to lose state from parent component to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a view which shows all posts. There's a filter above those posts and user can filter posts depending on what options he chooses. After he chooses the options, filtered posts get returned.

Let's say user filtered posts and after that clicked on one of the posts, it means that parent component which was showing posts will be destroyed. If now, user(who is on the specific post page) clicks back button, it will take him to all posts page, but filters won't be persisted since parent component got destroyed and then created.

One solution to persist filters and filtered posts after clicking back button from specific page is to use vuex. when user chooses filters, we store the object in vuex. when user clicks back button, store would already have the filters. The problem is following this way causes some problems for me and takes much more time.

Any other way you can think of ? I can't use `keep-alive` since it seems i can only use it for dynamic components and not any other way.

Comment: Just store the filter further up the component tree so it doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: That's not the way. it seems like i was wrong and they are not related as parent-child

Comment: Ok, but does it really matter? Just store the filter high enough so it doesn't get destroyed. Why is that "not the way"?

Comment: That's the problem mate.. I just looked at (specific post page and all posts page) are two different routes.

Comment: I'm not sure why that means my suggestion won't work? Vue children can [emit events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events), which means the filter component can send the chosen filter up the tree to a parent that won't get destroyed, and upon navigating back to "all posts", the filter is passed down again and active.

Comment: If they are two different pages then the filter data will be lost regardless. Maybe you could use local storage to store the current filter then on page load, change the filter to what is in local storage.

Comment: Vuex, to persist state between component creation sounds perfect to me. Maybe you could elaborate on the vuex problems you're having.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here:

1. [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) - it's used for state management, best to use when you need to communicate between 2+ components. You can will need a set of methods that will update the filter values in your store, e.g.:

```
const store = {
  category: null,
  tag: null,
  date: null
}

const actions = {
  updateFilter({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('updateFilter', payload); // example payload structure: { filterName: 'category', filterValue: 'reviews' }
  }
}

const mutations = {
  updateFilter(state, payload) {
    state[payload.filterName] = payload.filterValue;
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  store,
  actions,
  mutations
}
```

And you need to bind these actions to via `@click` events on your website. Then you need to bind the values from the store with your filters method (probably also you'll want to execute filtering method when your posts list changes, so you can use [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)  for example)

2. If you're using [Vue router](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router) and [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html), you can store your filters via [query params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html):

```
router.push({ path: 'blog', query: { category: 'reviews' }})
```

So your url will become `blog?category=reviews` - and when you change your url to clicked article and then click back, you'll go first to the url with latest query params set you had (but of course you need to create a method that will filter out on component create the post list based on provided filters)

The additional win for the 2nd option is that you'll be able to share the link with other people (so they will gonna see the filtered posts in the same way as you do).